# Jackson transfor POJO to XML avoid list Wrapper

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I am trying to get an output without a root node for a list.
I will simplify my code with a more simple idea :

```
    @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "my_company")
    public class Company {

     //Creating properties of Company class
     public String comName;
     public String comEmail;

     @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
     public List<Parent> childs;

     // constructor
     Company(String comName, String comEmail, List<Parent> childs) {
        this.comName = comName;
        this.comEmail = comEmail;
        this.childs = childs;
     }

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
    class Parent{

    }
    @JsonTypeName("my_child")
     class Child extends Parent{
      public String street;
      public String state;
      public String city;

      Child(String street, String state, String city){
         this.street = street;
         this.state = state;
         this.city = city;
     }
  }
```

This is the result i get :

```
   <my_company>
       <comName>A</comName>
       <comEmail>ema</comEmail>
       <childs>
         <my_child>
           <street>a</street>
           <state>b</state>
          <city>c</city>
        </my_child>
       </childs>
       <childs>
        <my_child>
          <street>a</street>
          <state>b</state>
          <city>c</city>
        </my_child>
       </childs>
   </my_company>
```

I dont want that , I need to remove "childs" tag ,i wanna this :

```
    <my_company>
        <comName>A</comName>
        <comEmail>ema</comEmail>
          <my_child>
             <street>a</street>
             <state>b</state>
             <city>c</city>
          </my_child>
         <my_child>
            <street>a</street>
            <state>b</state>
            <city>c</city>
         </my_child>
    </my_company>
```

***@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)*** should do the trick,but i tried 1 millon different combinations,documentation,forum,etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Company` has no `address` and `contacts` instance variables

Comment: I already edit the code. I had to make an adaptation from existing code to make things more clear .Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

before I specify the solution, I would like to point out several problems with the code:

1. It doesn't compile (`Company` class has no `address` and `contacts` instance variables that are specified in constructor). I removed these properties.
2. `Company` class holds list of `Parent` items, but `Parent` is an empty class with no relation to `Child`. I removed `Parent`.

The solution is to specify two Jackson xml annotations for `List<Child>` instance variable of `Company`:

1. the obvious `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)`
2. `@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "my_child")` tells Jackson what to name the list item
3. no annotations are required for `Child` class itself.

`Company` class looks like this

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "my_company")
public class Company {

    //Creating properties of Company class
    public String comName;
    public String comEmail;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "my_child")
    public List<Child> childs;

    // constructor ...
```

test method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Company.Child> childs = List.of(
            new Company.Child("a", "b", "c"),
            new Company.Child("d", "e", "f")
    );
    Company company = new Company("A", "ema", childs);
    try {
        XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
        mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(System.out, company);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

output

```
<my_company>
  <comName>A</comName>
  <comEmail>ema</comEmail>
  <my_child>
    <street>a</street>
    <state>b</state>
    <city>c</city>
  </my_child>
  <my_child>
    <street>d</street>
    <state>e</state>
    <city>f</city>
  </my_child>
</my_company>
```

Comment: Thanks ! The problem with that ,is that Company do not have a List of Child like you added. If you look my example,it says "     public List<Parent> childs; " . So ,i can not use a harcoded name (    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "my_child")) . Because ,each child is gonna have its own name (    @JsonTypeName("my_child") . Maybe i have another class extending from Parent with the following root annotation (    @JsonTypeName("my_child_2")

Comment: And the output with my above commente ,should be  
<my_child>
    <street>a</street>
    <state>b</state>
    <city>c</city>
  </my_child>
  <my_child_2>
    <street>d</street>
    <state>e</state>
    <city>f</city>
  </my_child_2>